# What do you call the supervisord and php-fpm et. al. config format?

Tags: files, configuration, settings

Both php-fpm and [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#unix-http-server-section-example) use a config format that looks like this:

```
[category]
settings = value
some_other_setting = value
```

Is there a name for this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an [ini file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) or initialisation file.

The part in square brackets in called a section:

```
; comment
[section]
key=value
```